# Usage of "X or similar"

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions

While reviewing some text written by a colleague I encountered this situation:

> you should use X *or similar tool*

which sounds incorrect to me. I feel a correct text here would be one of these

1. you should use X *or a similar tool*
2. you should use X *or similar*
3. you should use X *or similar tools*

But I can't articulate why, and being a non-native english speaker there's a chance I'm just projecting my native grammar onto the english one.

Which option is correct, and why?

Comment: I would use either 1 or 3.  Since "X" is named, it doesn't require an article.  However, "similar tool" is not a name, so you must put an article when it's singular.  In 3, it is plural, so you do not need the article.  I'm not sure if 2 is grammatical, but I think it is.  Nonetheless, it sounds unnatural (to me), so I would probably avoid it.

Comment: They are all grammatical. And I've heard *or similar* (with nothing else after) used often enough that it sounds natural to me.